# How to use React Native Navigation. like stack Navigation

Tags: react-native

This is my first time developing React Native. However, no matter what information is searched, react navigation cannot be used due to TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating'_RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction') error. Does anyone have a good example of how to do it?

Comment: I want android dev

Comment: Did you install this package?

Comment: yes but I don't know if I did it right.

Comment: Are you using expo?

Comment: no i used react native cli

Comment: As I guess you are using wix react-native-navigation, right?

Answer (score 0):

pod install on ios

```
cd ios
pod install
```

More detail can be found here [react-native-gesture-handler#676](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/676) and [react-native-gesture-handler#494](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/494)

Comment: Thk your comment
I use Windows and i want android dev

Comment: @PlzDontErorr have you tried by cleaning project `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Comment: I have already tried this and failed. I do not know what is the problem.